# reportlab: how to detect pagebreak?

Tags: python, reportlab

I am using reportlab to display large tables. I have a table with a subtitle (Paragraph), but when I put multiple subtitles and tables side by side, only the title is left on the previous page, depending on the size of the table. Is there a good way to avoid this?

I tried to calculate the table height and Paragraph height but could not get the Paragraph height to work.

Comment: I think that template is probably not usable either, since it also contains a table of different conditions.